# Special characters in @QueryParam name in Spring feign client

Tags: spring, query-string, wiremock, feign

One of our external API uses query param names with special characters (don't ask me why, I don't know). My feign client's method for this API is declared like this:

```
@GetMapping("/v1/user/{userId}/orders")
List<Order> getOrders(
    @PathVariable("userId") String userId,
    @RequestParam("page[number]") Integer pageNumber,
    @RequestParam("page[size]") Integer pageSize);
```

As I mentioned, request params contain special characters `[` and `]`.
I'm using Spock for testing and I want to set up Wiremock stub like this:

```
wiremock.stubFor(
  get(urlPathMatching('/v1/users/' + userId + '/orders'))
    .withQueryParam("page[number]", new EqualToPattern("1"))
    .withQueryParam("page[size]", new AnythingPattern())
    .willReturn(
      status(200)
        .withHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        .withBody("""[]""")
    ))
```

But I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                        | Request                                                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                      |
GET                                   | GET
/v1/users/123/orders                  | /v1/users/123/orders?page%5Bnumber%5D=%7Bpage%5Bnumber%5
                                      | D%7D&page%5Bsize%5D=%7Bpage%5Bsize%5D%7D
                                      |
Query: page[number] = 1               |                                 <<<<< Query is not present
Query: page[size] [anything] (always) |                                 <<<<< Query is not present
                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After lots of trials and errors, I came up with a solution to use `@PathVariable`s instead of `@RequestParam`s in feign client method:

```
@GetMapping("/v1/users/{userId}/orders?page[number]={pageNumber}&page[size]={pageSize}")
List<Order> getOrders(
    @PathVariable("userId") String userId,
    @PathVariable("pageNumber") Integer pageNumber,
    @PathVariable("pageSize") Integer pageSize);
```

and encode all query params in Wiremock

```
wiremock.stubFor(
    get(urlPathMatching('/v1/users/' + userId + '/orders'))
    .withQueryParam("page%5Bnumber%5D", new EqualToPattern("1"))
    .withQueryParam("page%5Bsize%5D", new AnythingPattern())
    .willReturn(
        status(200)
        .withHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        .withBody("""[]""")
    ))
```

Then it works. But it looks like a kind of a hack. It is problematic to use an optional query params as well.

Is there a way to use `@RequestParam`s with special characters?
It looks like a bug in Spring?

In the mean time I will try to debug it to understand where is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's not a bug in Spring. The main goal of these spring-like annotations (`@RequestParam`, `@RequestMapping` etc. from `spring-web`) is to use them in Spring MVC controllers on the server-side and not for create urls for requests.

In the case of Feign clients, there is another library, `spring-cloud-openfeign`, which allows you to have them in Feign Clients for request mapping instead of original Feign annotations (like `@RequestLine`, `@Param` and so on). `SpringMvcContract` is responsible for it, and [it is used by default in Spring applications](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults). But it's just for the convenience of this specific group of developers who're using Feign with Spring, so it's not a reason to change signatures of these annotations or add them some new settings.

About described problem - seems like there isn't any "official" way to disable url encoding even if you're using original Feign annotations for request mapping - at the moment (**version 10.7.4**), you can only do it for slashes (check [this issue](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/537), for example).

I've performed some further investigation and come to these points:

1. While constructing the request query template, you cannot set the encoding option manually, because it's just hardcoded (look at [UriTemplate](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/template/UriTemplate.java#L73) and [QueryTemplate](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/template/QueryTemplate.java#L126) source code).
2. You can actually fix the constructed url later by writing your own `RequestInterceptor` (by reflection, f.e.), but it's actually pointless because [after applying all interceptors the request is built](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/SynchronousMethodHandler.java#L163) and, at the moment, it implicitly encodes the brackets again ([check](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/RequestTemplate.java#L278) what's happened under the hood, basically it uses `queryTemplate.toString()` which, in turn, encodes brackets while using methods of [UriUtils](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/template/UriUtils.java) class)
3. After the request creation, it is started to execute by `Client`, and I actually managed to fix the url at this step. I inherited a class from the standard `Client.Default`, registered it instead of the original auto-configurated one, and then I did my job before actually invoking the client (ofc it's possible to do the same for a different client, f.e., for `LoadBalancerFeignClient`):

```
import feign.Client;
import feign.Request;
import feign.Response;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@Component
public class MyClient implements Client {

    private Client delegate;

    public MyClient() {
        this.delegate = new Client.Default(null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request, Request.Options options) throws IOException {
        fixRequestUrlIfPossible(request);
        return delegate.execute(request, options);
    }

    private void fixRequestUrlIfPossible(Request request) {
        try {
            Field urlField = ReflectionUtils.findField(Request.class, "url");
            urlField.setAccessible(true);

            String encodedUrl = (String) urlField.get(request);
            String url = encodedUrl.replace("%5B", "[").replace("%5D", "]");
            urlField.set(request, url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*NOP*/
        }
    }
}
```

But it's error prone because of the reflection (can stop work in later versions of Feign).

So, it's up to you - if you're not afraid of doing this kind of things, use this approach. I actually like your version more. The main question is: is your real server able to handle requests with encoded brackets? Problems with Wiremock are less important, in my opinion.